# Is converting Python unicode by casting to str reversible?

Tags: python, string, unicode

The proper way to convert a unicode string `u` to a (byte)string in Python is by calling `u.encode(someencoding)`.

Unfortunately, I didn't know that before and I had used `str(u)` for conversion. In particular, I called `str(u)` to coerce `u` to be a string so that I can make it a valid shelve key (which must be a str).

Since I didn't encounter any `UnicodeEncodeError`, I wonder if this process is reversible/lossless. That is, can I do `u = str(converted_unicode)` (or `u = bytes(converted_unicode)` in Python 3) to get the original `u`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, if the conversion with `str()` was successful, then you can reverse the result. Using `str()` on a `unicode` value is the equivalent of using `unicode_value.encode('ascii')` and the reverse is to simply use `str_value.decode('ascii')`. Using `unicode(str_value)` will use the same implicit ASCII codec to decode.

In Python 3, calling `str()` on a unicode value simply gives you the same object back, since in Python 3 `str()` *is* the Unicode type. Using `bytes()` on a Unicode value without an encoding fails, you always have to use explicit codecs in Python 3 to convert between `str` and `bytes`.